# Why is Django testrunner not finding the tests I created?

Tags: python, django

I had been trying to add tests to a project I'm working on.

The tests are in forum/tests/

When I run manage.py test  it doesn't find any of the tests I created, on the tests in Django 1.2

I started with all my tests in their own package but have simplified down to just being in my tests.py file. The current tests.py looks like:

```
from django.test.client import Client  
from django.test import TestCase  
from utils import *   
from forum.models import *  
from forum import auth  

class ForumTestCase(TestCase):  
    def test_root_page(self):  
        response = self.client.get('/')  
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)  

    def test_signin_page(self):  
        response = self.client.get("/account/signin/")  
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

I'm sure I am missing something very basic and obvious but I just can't work out what. Any ideas?

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (  
    'django.contrib.auth',  
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',  
    'django.contrib.sessions',  
    'django.contrib.sites',  
    'django.contrib.admin',  
    'django.contrib.humanize',  
    'forum',  
    'django_authopenid',  
)
```

Why would Django testrunner not be finding the tests I created?

The tests are at forum/tests/:

```
__init__.py
forum/tests/test_views.py  
forum/tests/test_models.py
```

I also have a `__init__.py` file in the directory.

Comment: Where exactly are the tests? /forum/tests/tests.py, or /forum/tests.py?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As noted in the comment, Django 1.6 introduced backwards-incompatibility with **[discovery of tests in any test module](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.6/#discovery-of-tests-in-any-test-module)**.

Before Django 1.6, one would have to do the following:

Create file named `__init__.py` in

```
forum/tests/__init__.py
```

And import all test from other moduls inside it.

```
from test_views import SomeTestCase
from test_models import SomeOtherTestCase
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't mention I already had it setup like that, EDITED above.

Comment: This is not needed for Django 1.6+, so hide it behind a test of django.VERSION